# Can't compile C++ code - "undefined reference to--"

Tags: c++

so I'm doing some homework for my CompSci 2 class and have hit a couple snags.  I can compile NBAplayer.h fine, but compiling client.cpp produces:

> client.cpp:(.text+0x10a): undefined reference to
>   `NBAplayer::setName(std::basic_string,
>   std::allocator >)'

And trying to compile NBAplayer.cpp produces the following:

> /usr/lib/gcc/i686-redhat-linux/4.5.1/../../../crt1.o: In function
>   `_start': (.text+0x18): undefined reference to`main' collect2: ld
>   returned 1 exit status

These are the three files I have:

**client.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "NBAplayer.h"
using namespace std;

int main() {
    struct NFLPlayer{
        string name;
        string currentTeam;
        string Position;
        string School;
    };

    bool playerCheck;
    int playerType;
    string playerName;
    string playerTeam;
    string playerPosition;
    string playerSchool;
    playerCheck = false;
    NBAplayer player1;
    while(playerCheck == false)
    {
        cout << "What kind of player would you like to create? (Enter 1 for NBA, 2 for NFL): "
             << endl;
        cin  >> playerType;
        if(playerType = 1) {
        }
        else if(playerType = 2) {
            cout << "Please enter your NBA Player's name: "
                 << endl;
            cin >> playerName;
            player1.setName(playerName);
        }
        else {
            cout << "Please check your input and try again!"
                 << endl;
        }
    }
};
```

**NBAplayer.h**

```
#include <string>

class NBAplayer {
    private:
        std::string name;
        std::string team;
        char position;
        std::string school;
    public:
        void setName(std::string playerName);
        void setTeam(std::string teamName);
        void setPosition(char playerPosition);
        void setSchool(std::string schoolName);
        std::string getName();
        std::string getTeam();
        char getPosition();
        std::string getSchool();
};
```

**NBAplayer.cpp**

```
#include "NBAplayer.h"
#include <string>

void NBAplayer::setName(std::string playerName) {
        name = playerName;
}
std::string NBAplayer::getName() {
    return name;
}
void NBAplayer::setTeam(std::string teamName) {
    team = teamName;
}
std::string NBAplayer::getTeam() {
    return team;
}
void NBAplayer::setPosition(char playerPosition) {
    position = playerPosition;
}
char NBAplayer::getPosition() {
    return position;
}
void NBAplayer::setSchool(std::string schoolName) {
    school = schoolName;
}
std::string NBAplayer::getSchool() {
    return school;
}
```

I've read through quite a few stackoverflow questions referencing this, but I have a feeling I'm doing something wrong since I'm unable to compile. If you need any more information, please let me know!

Comment: The fact it's through putty is irrelevant.

Comment: @Qix I wasn't sure, someone had asked for that in one of the questions I'd read through earlier so I figured it wouldn't hurt to provide it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You shouldn't compile a header file, so don't compile `NBAPlayer.h`.
2. You aren't *linking* your files together. You can do this by compiling each file individually using `-c` (to compile, not link), then compile the resulting `.o` files together. Or you can just give `g++` all of the source files at once, which will ask it to compile and link them together.

Comment: When you say "Give g++ all the source files at once" do you mean just use a single g++ command to compile everything? I...don't know why I didn't think of that.

Answer (score 0):

1 when you encounter the error `undefined reference to`, actually , it's not a complier error but a linker error(The complie process includes complie, link and  load).As you seee, you will find `collect2: ld returned 1 exit status`,which come from linkers.

when you complie client.cpp, you get

`undefined reference to NBAplayer::setName(std::basic_string, std::allocator >)`

because you don't compile NBAplayer.cpp together.The linker can't find the implements of `NBAplayer::setName`.

2 when you compile NBAplayer.cpp , you get

`undefined reference to main`

that's because you just want compile NBAplayer.cpp to a executable object, but every cpp must have a main func, and you don't have one , so you get that problem .

3 you should do like this :`g++ client.cpp NBAplayer.cpp -o main`, compile both of them .